# How to make an operator that is like Ruby <=> (a.k.a.: spaceship)

Tags: android, spaceship-operator

I have a sample code below that is made with swift and using <=> 
,I want to convert it to android but I have no clue how to do.I want to convert the following sample
to android with java. Some tips or examples will be great! I would love to hear from you.

```
let sortItems = self.getSortItems(item: itm) <=> self.getSortItems(item: itm2)
let sortIt = itm.checker <=> itms2.checker
if sortIt != 0 {
    return sortIt * -1
}
```

Comment: Ruby's `<=>` is roughly equivalent to Java `Comparable`'s `.compareTo` function.

Comment: It would be lovely if you can show me how to do it? I'm so new to Java :)

Comment: You can literally rewrite `A <=> B` into `A.compareTo(B)`.